# Is a Weierstrass curve a topological manifold?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, curves

Obviously a Weierstrass curve is not a smooth manifold, but it seems like a Weierstrass curve should be a topological manifold (which I now see is a suspicion supported by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206306/how-do-i-prove-that-a-graph-is-a-topological-manifold) post), since it is a continuous image of the real line.

That said, I am a particularly concerned about the locally Euclidean requirement.  I know that a Weiestrass curve generally has a non-integer Hausdorff dimension (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fractals_by_Hausdorff_dimension))--does that impact this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Weierstraß curve $W \subset \mathbb R ^2$ is the graph $G(w) = \{ (x,w(x) \mid  \in J \}$ of a Weierstraß function $w : J \to \mathbb R$ (which is continuous but nowhere differentiable). Here $J$ is an interval. The map $i : J \to G(w), i(x) = (x,w(x))$, is a homeomorphism. This is true for any graph of any continuous function $f : X \to Y$ between toplogical spaces.

Therefore $G(w)$ is a topological manifold. It is also a topological submanifold of $\mathbb R ^2$. See my answer to [The graph of $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ can be embbeded in $\mathbb R^2$ or only in $\mathbb R^3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3083501).

Moreover, it can be given the structure of a differentiable manifold: Simply take the single chart $i^{-1} : G(w) \to J$. However, it is not a *differentiable submanifold* of $\mathbb R ^2$.

Hausdorff dimension is not related to your question. It is not invariant under homeomorphisms. See [Is the Hausdorff dimension invariant under homeomorphisms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2061285).

Comment: Ah, very good.  I especially appreciate your comments about differentiability and the Hausdorff dimension.